# How does Google spreadsheet update showing multiple user edits in real time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets

I was working on Google Spreadsheets and it updates in real time with multiple users working. I opened up the network tab to see how the spreadsheets are updated in real time.
Was it a periodic API call which fetches the page state from the backend? Or it is updating via sockets?

However I did not see any requests being sent/received in the network tab while the page keeps updating. Even if there is an API call, the response is coming after the page updates.

I wanted to know how this technology works. Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: Sockets make a connection once and then send data without needing to make a new call

Comment: I checked the network tab and there is a request called `bind?id=***` which takes very long and updates when changes are made so it's probably [long polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet)

Comment: Yes @Konrad but I think you also get the logs in network tab when you get data via socket.